Is there a difference between NT Presidential and Wincore 5400 Windows?
We recently had all the windows in our house completely replaced. 23 windows in total in South Texas. The contract we signed listed Wincore 5400 with Cardinal LoE-366 glass.
Installers show up months later and install the windows, everything seems fine. There's some punch list stuff, but otherwise okay. In going over the contract before payment, it clicked that the windows they installed were NT Presidential windows instead of the Wincore 5400 listed on the contract. It had been so long between signing the contract the installers showing up, I didn't even notice.
So, my question is: does anybody have any information on the quality of the two brands? I will be going through and comparing the absolute metrics, like SHGC and U-factor, but I'm curious about the frames and whatnot. They NT windows use little fuzzy felt seals everywhere, for example, which I don't remember seeing on the Wincore windows (but again, it's been a while).

Read the contract about substitutions.  This is probably more legal than DIY range.  Unless something might kill you, we do not get into differences between brands.  Some electric panels are dangerous and we will recommend getting them change now or before, but other stuff it is up to you to find/search out.
